# Subnumbering equations while also aligning them

Tags: equations, amsmath, alignment

Using AMSMATH's `gather` environment I can subnumber equations, hoewever I am also losing the alignment at the "=". Is there a way to have both, alignment and subnumbering?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
x = a +  b +c \label{eq:gat}\\
sddsdt = a + b + d \tag{\ref{eq:gat}a} \\
yfgfdg = a + b + d \tag{\ref{eq:gat}b}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image: subequations_nonaligned]

Comment: Did you try this approach with align instead of gather? There is nothing special about gather here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note it is very easy to have a subnumbering like you seem to want, and cross-referencing it

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cleveref} 

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  a = b
\end{equation}

\begin{subequations}
    \begin{align}
    x & = a + b +c\label{eq:gat}\tag{\theequation}\\
    sddsdt & = a + b + d\label{eq:gat1} \\
    yfgfdg & = a + b + d \label{eq:gat2}
    \end{align}
\end{subequations}
We see from \eqref{eq:gat}, \eqref{eq:gat1} and \eqref{eq:gat2} that $1 = 2$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd prefer doing `\label{eq:gat}` after `\begin{subequations}` and `\tag{\ref{eq:gat}}` in the first line of the alignment. Cleaner than using `\theequation`.